# Use Django Variables from Admin

Tags: python, django, variables, django-admin

I haven't been able to find the answer to this because the common words return a lot of irrelevant answers in search engines..

How can I utilize Django variables and the `{% url %}` tag from within the Django admin section?

I want to enter things such as:

```
{{ object.property }}
{{ STATIC_URL }}
{% url %}
```

But these values are not appearing in the rendered template.. Thanks for any ideas!

To clarify: I want to enter a django variable into a field in the Django Admin Backend and have its value reflected in the rendered template.

---

The view in question:

```
def blog_detail(request, slug):
    blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)    
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'object':blog})
```

The model attributes:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField()
    article = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField("Enable comments", default=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/', null=True, blank=True)

    preview_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    preview_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

So the problem is that I want to input a django variable into `preview_location`, since the location will differ depending on which specific `Blog` entry I am currently viewing. Each `Blog` entry will have its own `preview_location`..

Comment: You want to find the django templates ?

Comment: You want to use the template syntax into data of a model object, right? For example, make an entry of a blog with `{{ STATIC_URL }}`?

Comment: Yes exactly @MaximeLorant! How do I accomplish this? Seems like a high use case that must be done often.. Thanks for any ideas

Comment: so essentially you want something kinda like how shortcodes work in wordpress wysiwyg fields?

Comment: Yes exactly @FrancisYaconiello. I know it should be possible, but no clue where to start.. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I've never used it, but: https://github.com/martey/django-shortcodes

Comment: Thanks @FrancisYaconiello. This may be a little different than what I am looking for, though.. Really I just want a way to include a django variable such as `{{ object.name }}` into the backend django admin section and have its value reflected in the rendered template in the django frontend (such as `This is the object's name`). Does that make sense? Since I have included the `object` in my view, it does not make sense why including the variable in the backend does not render its value..

Answer (score 0):

You can create "render" template filter and use it in your templates, and use it like

`{{ object.description|render }}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create a custom tag or a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) which will create a `Template` renderer object, populate the context with every variables you want to be accessible and render the template from the string. A simple filter could be:

```
from django.template import Context, Template
from django.conf import settings 

@register.filter
def render_string(string_tpl):
    tpl = Template(string_tpl)
    data = {"settings": settings, "another_stuff": 42}
    return tpl.render(Context(data))
```

And then you can use it as (once this new filter has been loaded):

```
{{ "My media URL is {{ settings.MEDIA_URL }}"|render_to_string }}
{{ your_tpl_string|render }}
```

As discuss in comments, you can pass additional objects to put in the context by creating a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag
def render_string(string_tpl, *args, **kwargs):
    tpl = Template(string_tpl)
    data = {"settings": settings}
    data.update(kwargs)  # add every additional items passed

    return tpl.render(Context(data))
```

And use it like:

```
{% render_string "My media URL is {{ settings.MEDIA_URL }}" %}
{% render_string "My media URL is {{ settings.MEDIA_URL }}, and my funny object: {{ object.name }}" object=object_in_cur_context %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MaximeLorant. I'm a little confused though, sadly. Where do I call `render_string`?

Comment: Just to be clear.. I want to enter something like `{{ object.name }}` into the backend Django admin section, and have the value of the variable ( such as `Object Name`) appear in the instance of the rendered template on the frontend. Is this what you are referencing?

Comment: Alright, there was several typos in my initial post (excuse my tiredness). You can use this filter to use settings and general stuff. If you want to be able to pass an object, you might need to create a tag (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).

Comment: Note that you are forced to give the object to the context when you are rendering the string, Django can't know by magic what object you mean, so you need to define a convention *"`{{ object }}` means the current object"* and pass object=... every time you render the string :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help @MaximeLorant. I copied the exact code into a templatetag file, put `__init__.py` in the directory, and registered the tag. Then using it in the django backend still does not produce the intended results, showing instead `{% render_string "My media URL is {{ settings.MEDIA_URL }}" %}` in the template itself.. What could I be missing?

Comment: You need to use the tag when you are displaying the object, not in the admin field! If the field you fill in the admin is `content`, you have to do `{% render_string object.content object=object %}` for example.

Answer (score 0):

so lets say that hypothetically you have a model instance named `obj` which has a field named `content` that has some django template jargon stored in it like so:

```
{{ object.property }}
{{ STATIC_URL }}
{% url %}
```

you could use the `Template` object and just render that content

```
from django.template import Template
tpl = Template(obj.content)
rendered_content = tpl.render({'a' : 123, 'b' : 456}) #variables?
```

but how do you inherently know what variables to pass through?

maybe you pass request context and the `obj` instance as a dict?

```
from django.template import Template
from django.template import RequestContext

context = RequestContext(request, {'obj': obj})  

tpl = Template(obj.content)
rendered_content = tpl.render(context)
```

and then pass `rendered_content` from your view to your template?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I understand conceptually, but having problems implementing this into my view. I have tried a variety of methods, but have added the view above. If you have any ideas on how to implement into my view I would be ever so grateful! Thanks for any ideas.